# Coldfusion insert record into Oracle DB

Tags: oracle, coldfusion, sql-insert

I'm trying to insert records from Coldfusion into Oracle DB 11(g) but the error log shows ORA-00911: invalid character. I able select the records from Oracle DB but unable to insert.

Below is my codes.

```
<cfquery name="qOracleData" datasource="Oracle_Test">
    Insert into postindept (deptid, propos_position, descr, sm_descr60, grade) values ('1','110000  ', '110000  ','510000 ' ,'10');
    COMMIT;
</cfquery>
```

Comment: Are the spaces in the values `'110000  '` and `'510000 '` intentional? Have you tried without them? May be those fields are not integer and you are tring to insert other characters.

Comment: Yes, I have tried without the spaces and shows the same error. The fields are varchar.

Comment: What is the schema of the table? Are you certain those columns are varchar? What size of varchar?

Answer (score 8):

Oracle only supports a single statement per query. Remove the `COMMIT;` (which you don't need as the transaction should automatically commit) and the trailing semi-colon from the insert statement.

Also, if you are inserting numeric values then you shouldn't pass them as strings:

```
<cfquery name="qOracleData" datasource="Oracle_Test">
    Insert into postindept (
      deptid, propos_position, descr, sm_descr60, grade
    ) values (
      1,      110000,          110000, 510000,    10
    )
</cfquery>
```

and you could use [bind parameters](https://helpx.adobe.com/uk/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-p-q/cfqueryparam.html):

```
<cfquery name="qOracleData" datasource="Oracle_Test">
    Insert into postindept (
      deptid,
      propos_position,
      descr,
      sm_descr60,
      grade
    ) values (
      <cfqueryparam value = "1"      cfsqltype = "CF_SQL_NUMERIC" />,
      <cfqueryparam value = "110000" cfsqltype = "CF_SQL_NUMERIC" />,
      <cfqueryparam value = "110000" cfsqltype = "CF_SQL_NUMERIC" />,
      <cfqueryparam value = "510000" cfsqltype = "CF_SQL_NUMERIC" />,
      <cfqueryparam value = "10"     cfsqltype = "CF_SQL_NUMERIC" />
    )
</cfquery>
```

Comment: I have used your method but still showing invalid characters.

Comment: @Gary The query works in Oracle [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=b10c0692958d8e8a9f8f2f9ffae3ca7e) and it also works if I copy/paste from your code in the question (after deleting the `; COMMIT;`) [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=c4e33df8bcfa3356243ec0802e7210e5). Check that there are not any characters from extended character sets that you can't see that might cause the issue.